# DevExtreme DropDownBox Problem on First Selection Changed

Tags: devextreme

I've been learning to use the DevExteme HTML 5 widgets. I've followed the code sample [here](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Widgets/DropDownBox/Overview/), except the data is coming from a remote API.

The code is:

```
let containerForRemoteObjectDropDown = document.createElement("div");

var dropOptions4 = {
  value: 10409,
  valueExpr: "orderId",
  valueExpr: "shipCountry",
  dataSource: {
    store: AspNetData.createStore({
      loadUrl: "https://localhost:44341/nwind/orders",
      key: "orderId"
    }),
    sort: "shipCountry",
    paginate: true,
    pageSize: 100 // group
  },
  contentTemplate: function(e) {
    let divForGrid = document.createElement("div");
    var grid = new DataGrid(divForGrid, {
      dataSource: e.component.option("dataSource"),
      columns: ["orderId", "shipCountry"],
      height: 265,
      selection: { mode: "single" },
      selectedRowKeys: [selectedValue],
      onSelectionChanged: function(selectedItems) {
        var keys = selectedItems.selectedRowKeys,
          hasSelection = keys.length;
        e.component.option("value", hasSelection ? keys[0] : null);
        e.component.close();
      }
    });
    return divForGrid;
  }
};

container.appendChild(containerForRemoteObjectDropDown);

let remoteDatadropDownInstance = new DropDownBox(
  containerForRemoteObjectDropDown,
  dropOptions4
);
```

The problem is, when you first click on the DropDownBox, the `onSelectionChanged` event fires and the dropdown part of the widget closes. This is meant to happen when you actually select an item in the likst, not when you click on the widget to first invoke the dropdown part of the control.

Here is an animated gif of it:

[image]

Is anyone aware of what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have phase same issue when integrate dropdown. same as this code
https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DropDownBox/SingleSelection/jQuery/Light/

this phase when data bind from api call, not with static js file. 
Then i have done some changes below.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
this phase when data bind from api call, not with static js file. Then i have done some changes below.